# Game Jolt game package still running after game crash

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, game-jolt, around-the-clock-at-bikini-bottom

I installed the game Around the Clock at Bikini Bottom on Game Jolt, I open up the game to have it crash, but Game Jolt says the package is still running and I have limited things that I can seem to do.

I have shut down my PC multiple times and I have deleted the files before as well, but Game Jolt says it's still running the package and so I can't remove it from my library. Game Jolt will not give me the option to uninstall or close the game. Also, the game runs in 64 bit and my computer does as well so I'm not sure what to do.

[image: Game Lauch on main game jolt page]